# JSP - Passing String Array to a constructor

Tags: jsp, checkbox

I have jsp1 where user checks couple of check boxes
On jsp2 am successfully able to read the checkbox values using String.

But I also need to created a user object with the parameters selected on jsp1, so that I can write it to a text file. This is where I'm hitting a road block. When independently I ran the code is java console it's working fine. But the actual code isn't. I'm getting below error

```
An error occurred at line: 29 in the jsp file: /ProcessMyForm.jsp
The constructor User(String, String, String, String, String, String[], String) is undefined
26:         String path = sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/EmailList.txt");
27: 
28:         // use regular Java objects
29:        User user = new User(userName, emailAddress, password, comment, emailFormat, serverScript, occupation);
30:        UserIO.add(user, path);
31:     %>
32:
```

Below is the code where I'm reading the jsp values and trying to create an object

```
<%
    // get parameters from the request
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String emailAddress = request.getParameter("emailAddress");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String comment = request.getParameter("comment");
    String emailFormat = request.getParameter("emailFormat");
    String serverScript[] = request.getParameterValues("serverScript");
    String occupation = request.getParameter("occupation");



    ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
    String path = sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/EmailList.txt");


   User user = new User(userName, emailAddress, password, comment, emailFormat,  serverScript, occupation);
   UserIO.add(user, path);
%>
```

Below is the code for the constructor
    public class User
    {
    private String userName;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String password;
    private String comment;
    private String emailFormat;
    private String serverScript[]; 
    private String occupation;

```
@SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
public User()
{
    userName = "";
    password = "";
    emailAddress = "";
    comment = "";
    emailFormat = "";
    occupation = "";
}

public User(String userName, String emailAddress, String password, String comment, String emailFormat, String[] serverScript, String occupation)
{
this.userName = userName;
this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
this.password = password;
this.comment = comment;
this.emailFormat = emailFormat;
this.serverScript= serverScript;
this.occupation = occupation;

}
```

Would you please help me solve the issue. Please let me know if you need additional details

Answer (score 0):

When I closed and opened the Netbeans it worked.My professor told me that sometimes the updated class is not picked by the server.